# LibGDX Простые фигуры, но не ShapeRenderer

Tags: kotlin, libgdx

Вопрос очень короткий, есть ли возможность рисовать простые фигуры не используя ShapeRenderer, что еще есть в LibGDX?

Почему то, как я не пытался(уже кажется все перепробовал), но ShapeRenderer не виден(не ресует) в Desktop(( В эмуляторе Android рисует, а в Desktop нет

Answer (score 0):

Мда... видимо вопрос сложный, ну да ладно, сам решил...
Кому интересно, вот пример из моего Actor

```
    override fun draw(batch: Batch?, parentAlpha: Float) {
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha)
    batch!!.draw(sprite, x, y, originX, originY, width, height, scaleX, scaleY, rotation)

    val pixmap = Pixmap(circleAim.radius.toInt()*2+1, circleAim.radius.toInt()*2+1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888)
    pixmap.setColor(Color.RED)
    pixmap.drawCircle(circleAim.radius.toInt(), circleAim.radius.toInt(), circleAim.radius.toInt())
    batch.draw(Texture(pixmap),x - originX, y - originY)
}
```